# How to add a databinding to a value attribute in datatrigger in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have to fire a datatrigger event and compare two fields & check whether its true & set a style for it based on it

Below is my code snippet

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SKUL.ItemNumber}"   Value="{Binding ActiveSKULNavigationItem.Supersession.Source}" >
<Setter Property="Common:ButtonPopup.ButtonContent" >
<Setter.Value >
 <Image Source="{StaticResource CommentHighlighted16}" Height="16" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
```

i want to check SKUL.ItemNumber equals ActiveSKULNavigationItem.Supersession.Source.But the above code throws error.

if i hardcode value="aaa" it works.

Error:A binding cannot be set on the value property of type datatrigger.A binding can only be set on a dependency property of a dependency object

How can i solve it

Answer (score 0):

The error shows clearly what you are doing wrong. You cannot bind value of `DataTrigger`.
To solve this, add `IValueConverter` to your `DataTrigger.Binding` which will convert it to `bool` value. 
Code snippet:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" Value="True">
```

Converter (where `MyItem` is the class of bound object):

```
class MyConverter : IValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value as MyItem).SKUL.ItemNumber == (value as MyItem).ActiveSKULNavigationItem.Supersession.Source;
    }
}
```